# How to parse a JWT with express?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

i want to access the body json of a JWT that i read out with node.js and passport.

```
const passport = require('passport');
passport.use(new JWTStrategy(services.uaa));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.authenticate('JWT', {session: false}));

app.use(checkAuth);
function checkAuth(req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) {
  console.log(req);
  return next();
}
```

When i simply log req, it does not really look like a json. So i wonder, how can i parse the req object into a json? Do you have any hints? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`req` is a complex Express' object of type `Request`. 
If you want to access the headers, where the JWT is passed most of the time, you need to use:

```
req.get('Authorization') // or any other header: 'Content-Type', etc
```

Comment: cool! Of course as mentioned in other's answers as you use Passport's JWT implementation you may not need to access directly the token and you can probably rely on Passport's own methods.

Answer (score 1):

You are using passportjs along with `passport-jwt` . Take another look at the documentation how this strategy "extracts" the JWT Token (especially the "payload" that comes with it) from the request. [Passport-JWT Documentation](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-jwt/)

```js
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy,
      ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;

const opts = {
   jwtFromRequest : ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
   secretOrKey : 'secret',
   issuer : 'accounts.examplesoft.com',
   audience : 'yoursite.net'
}

passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {

    // jwt_payload is the payload that you earlier included 
    // in the jwt token, when you created the jwt token.

    // Here you can verify the request,
    // For example, check database if user exists. 

    User.findOne({id: jwt_payload.sub}, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err, false);
        }
        if (user) {
            return done(null, user);
        } else {
            return done(null, false);
            // or you could create a new account
        }
    });
}));
```

With this, you normally wouldn't need an additional "checkAuth" function. Use it like this :

```js
app.use(passport.authenticate('JWT', {session: false}));

// OR

app.post('/protected', passport.authenticate('JWT', {session: false}), (req, res) => {

   // this will only fire when authentication was successfull
   // req.user will hold whatever you return in the callback from
   // the strategy function. 

});
```